# Is Hibernate's javassist supposed to cause this behaviour?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

Ok, so I recently started learning hibernate, and I got Netbeans 8.0 and started going through the official Netbeans hibernate tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

However, when I arrived at the bit where I was to test my HQL ("from Film" - the query I ran), I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: dvdrental.Language_$$_javassist_60 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
```

There's a bunch of other stuff that follows that line, but that's not where I'm getting at.

The hibernate library I'm using came with Netbeans 8.0. So I went online, got the official Hibernate 4.3.6. I configured it on my netbeans, used it and got the same error.

Then I removed the javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, and the error disappeared. I was able to run my HQL with no problems. Same with removing the javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar that comes with my netbeans - that took care of all my problems.

Which brings me to my question: is this supposed to happen? javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar is in the required folder. Why on earth would I get errors when using it and not get any errors when omitting it?

And why am I getting this error in the first place?

The full error is below. Thanks for your help, guys.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: dvdrental.Language_$$_javassist_60 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3737)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:982)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got a solution to this problem. Apparently there appears to be a bug with Netbeans 8.0. After contacting Oracle, and update was released - Netbeans 8.0.1 which pretty much fixes all this problem. So, in other words, the problem had nothing to do with hibernate, but Netbeans.

So, if you're using Netbeans 8.0 ensure you update your IDE.

Thanks.